# Setting variables in *.fxml file from java class [edit:] with available Scene Builder

Tags: java, xml, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

I'm working on wizard installer in JavaFX and I need few windows with AnchorPnane with this same size. Now in *.fxml file I have lines:

```
 <AnchorPane prefHeight="300.0" prefWidth="300.0"
```

I will have few similar files *.fxml so I need keep information about size in my java class:

```
public final int HeightOfAnchorPane=300;
public final int WidthOfAnchorPane=300;
```

How can I set value of height and width to file *.fxml from my java class? Like this:

```
<AnchorPane prefHeight = HeightOfAnchorPane prefWidth= WidthOfAnchorPane
```

EDIT:
@james-d I thank you for this post: [How can I make constant variables in Javafx for XML files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31259166/how-can-i-make-constant-variables-in-javafx-for-xml-files) but if I import class in *.fxml file I couldn't open file with SceneBuilder. Someone can fix it?

Comment: @James_D I edited my post. If I import class to *.fxml file I couldn't open this file with SceneBuilder. Is other way?

Comment: To use your own classes in SceneBuilder, you have to bundle them into jar file(s) and import them into the SceneBuilder library. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30063792/adding-a-custom-component-to-scenebuilder-2-0